# PHP/MySQL Insert large data accross 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import data into my MySQL database from a large array which was saved in json format. I wrote a little script in JavaScript that goes through that array and sends all the relevant data through AJAX calls. My php file takes the data for 1 record, checks if all fields are valid and then proceeds to insert it into my main table. The data may also contain informations that are linked to the main entry. Perhaps 0, perhaps multiple lines, whichever the case, all of them get validated and inserted into another table, referencing the id of the main entry.

I will try to come up with a simple example to better illustrate what I'm trying to do:

data to insert:

```
source : { id: 0, f1: 50, f2: 100, f3: 310, 
    linked : [ l1: { d: "B", v: 32.50}, l2: { d: "C", v: 27.30} ]
}
```

And here is what my php file does in a simplified version:

```
if(valid($source)){ // validate passed data and proceed if they are valid
    //check passed id (id == 0 => insert,  id > 0 => update)
    if($source['id'] == 0){
        //INSERT new row into main_table
        $last_id = $pdo->lastInsertId(); //get new id

        //if there is additional data, insert each row into link_table
        if(!empty($source['linked']){
            foreach($source['linked'] ...){
                //validate linked data
                //INSERT INTO link_table (main_id, ...) VALUES(:source_id, ...);
            }
        }
    } else if($source['id'] > 0){
        //attempt UPDATING existing row in main_table where id = source.id
        $last_id = $source['id'];

        //...UPDATE linked data in link_table (where main_id = $last_id)
    }
}
```

And this does the job fine when handling a single record. (NOTE: I want to insert only new rows now so the UPDATE part is not relevant here.) I don't know what's the best way to insert thousands of rows, so without better alternative, my script sends an AJAX call for each record. I know this is **terrible** in many ways but it works. Needless to say, my local webserver gets really busy this way, and inserting 4000+ rows takes 30+ minutes. I do it through AJAX because I don't know how to insert my json data - which needs some tinkering to begin with.. - using a better way. I bet it wouldn't take more than a couple of seconds with the right queries, but how do I construct a query that inserts everything into my `main_table` and also inserts whatever linked rows there are into the `link_table`, based on the `main_table` id's?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you can do:

1. First, remove JS and the browser entirely, and only run the PHP script from an SSH windows. This will run a LOT faster without making any changes to the PHP.
2. If that is not enough, you will gain SOME speed by doing multiple inserts, like this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_multiple.asp

For point 2, note that there is a limit on how many you can run at once... I can't remember what it is now, and it might depend on the server config anyway... try with 100 to start with, and take it from there.

Comment: I see..!Not related to my question, but why is it processed a lot more slowly through the browser?

Comment: Well it's Ajax that is the main overkill here. Going through the browser also adds another app layer. Try running the exact same script via SSH shell, and time them... let me know what the difference is :o) and also grouping will help.